# json object posted to codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, json

I am making a very simple mistake but couldn't able to find it.
I posted JSON object to CodeIgniter controller using AJAX but was not able to retrieve this value in the controller function.
My code is

AJAX code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{eventdata:" + JSON.stringify(eventToSave) + "}",
    url: "<?php echo $base?>/index.php/welcome/addEvent",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {      
        alert(data);        
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
        $('.qtip').remove();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

In the console, JSON object is shown in following format:

```
{
    eventdata: {
        "EventID": 170,
        "StartDate": "Thu May 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
        "EndDate": "Thu May 10 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
        "EventName": "sdsfddsf"
    }
}
```

CodeIgniter addEvent function:

```
$json_output[]=(array)json_decode($this->input->post());        
print_r($json_output);
```

I have tried various other options also but couldn't able to get the value from json object which I need to store in database.Please tell me some way to retrieve this value from json object and then storing it in db

Answer (score 2):

Try this one if it work.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = stripslashes($json);
$json = json_decode($json);

convert the object array to array
$array =  (array) $json;
```

Comment: Hi Marvz73, can you specify how stripslashes($json) relates to the problem posed by the poster?

Comment: This is a very roundabout way of getting the POST data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong.

```
 url: "<?php echo $base?>/index.php/welcome/addEvent",
```

Are you sure you are actuelly hitting the right controller method? Did you check the source code?

Try doing something like this instead (using the URL Helper):

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/addEvent'); ?>",
```

Comment: heY Repox it's right url.Infact m able to call the right method in codeigniter controller.I defined the $base relative to my project.It is not at all causng d problem

Comment: Please tell me hw to retrieve this json object in php.